# Dynamic Checkbox is not getting checked in asp.net through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating checkbox dynamically, initially 2 queries r matched if the o/p of both the queries matches then in that case that specific checkbox get checked and disabled.............But in my case the matched checkbox corresponding to matched o/p of the queries get disabled but it does not get checked

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataSet ds = c.readDataSet("select teacher_id, name from teacher");
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                    chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.ID = "chk_" + drow[0].ToString();

                    SqlDataReader dr = c.readData("select t.teacher_id from teacher t join coordinator c on t.teacher_id=c.teacher_id where c.branch='" + ddl_class.Text + "' and c.cyear=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")+" and c.status=2" );
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if(dr.GetString(0)==drow[0].ToString())
                        {
                           chk.Checked = true;
                           chk.Enabled = false;
                           count = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    dr.Close();

                    chk.ToolTip = drow[1].ToString();
                    lb = new Label();
                    lb.Text = drow[1].ToString();
                    PnlCtrl.Controls.Add(chk);
                    PnlCtrl.Controls.Add(lb);
                    PnlCtrl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            }

}
```

Comment: Try to create totally new CheckBox handler inside the loop as: `CheckBox chk = new CheckBox()` (and not use the declaration somewhere outside).

Comment: @Aristos, have a look at my answer and tell me what you think. I'm pretty sure it's just because the .NET Framework is ignoring the control because of it's `Enabled` state.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes your answer is looks more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is happening because the `OnPreRender` of the `CheckBox` control ignores it when `Enabled` is set to `false`:

```
protected internal override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    bool autoPostBack = this.AutoPostBack;
    if (this.Page != null && base.IsEnabled)
    {
        this.Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
        if (autoPostBack)
        {
            this.Page.RegisterPostBackScript();
            this.Page.RegisterFocusScript();
            if (this.CausesValidation && this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count > 0)
            {
                this.Page.RegisterWebFormsScript();
            }
        }
    }
    if (!this.SaveCheckedViewState(autoPostBack))
    {
        this.ViewState.SetItemDirty("Checked", false);
        if (this.Page != null && base.IsEnabled)
        {
            this.Page.RegisterEnabledControl(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and that really isn't all that surprising. So, instead of setting `Checked = true` do this:

```
chk.Attributes.Add("checked", "checked");
```